# What is '**&**' symbol at the end in the command for?

Tags: linux

What is '**&**' symbol at the the end in the command for?

> nohup /server1/scripts/xyz.sh $1 2> nohup.out&

Comment: Duplicate of [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408)

Comment: Background it...

Answer (score 3):

The `&` character is a [control operator](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sh) in the shell. It causes to execute the process in the background. That means that the process has no read access to the terminal. Only a foreground process has. But, it can still write its output to the terminal

If you started a process in the background with:

```
process &
```

Then you can get him back to the foreground with:

```
fg
```

And you can interact with the process again.

Answer (score 0):

It moved the process to the background.

See your shell documentation and search for job control.

(PS: It is not linux specific).

Comment: May i know the meaning or use of & symbol at the end of the command?

Comment: Read the first sentence of my answer. The '&' moves the command to the background.